# Can Register renaming eliminate all WAR hazards?

Tags: computer-architecture

***Can Register renaming  eliminate all  WAR hazards?***

What I think is register renaming is not always successful because If CPU have limited number of registers and our programme is enormously large then required registers for renaming are much larger and register renaming will fail here.

Comment: The ROB size limits the number uncommitted instructions and the size of the issue queues limits the number of waiting-to-execute instructions. Generally the number of available registers is sufficient given these limits on the execution window (in a move-on-commit, a.k.a. data-ful ROB, the number of registers is always sufficient being equal to the ROB size). *Memory* WAR hazards are handled by another mechanism, the load-store queue.

Comment: okay it means practically it is not possible to be out of registers right?and for dealing with load/store operation a different kind of renaming is done where store operations are buffered in a store queue for a period of time.